# why background color is not set while using scss and css?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am using `scss` and `css` in my project . I have two file `styles.css` and `styles.css`.I imported both file in `_app.js`

```
import "../styles.scss";
import Head from "next/head";
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";
import "../styles.css";
```

in `style.css`

```
a {
  color: red;
}
```

and in my `styles.scss`

```
body {
  background-color: aqua
}
```

but `background color`  is not set .I am not sure why it is not set. I also using `scss loader` to compile my `scss` file.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-jennings-upb7y?file=/styles.scss:0-33

**NOTE** ::T**o run this project you need to create new terminal and run a command `npm run dev`.** because it run on 3004 port

my `webpack-config`

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");

module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  return withCss(
    withSass({
      webpack(config, { isServer }) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: "sass-loader",
                  options: {
                    additionalData: `$public_font_url: ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FONTS};`
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        });
        return config;
      }
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: `NOTE ::To run this project you need to create new terminal and run a command npm run dev. because it run on 3004 port`

Comment: I run the code and its successfully working, both css and scss

Comment: have you seen body background color ?

Comment: not the body bgc but all other property works fine

Comment: but I added `bgc` why it is not apply ?

Comment: I think this problem is related to codesandbox

Comment: no..same behaviour on my local machine that why I asked this question.I think my webpack configuration is wrong

Comment: you must use react helmet for that or Head component of that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, you must use the `Head` tag provided by `next.js`, there is no problem in your config file

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-sea-khlgr?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: if you found anything good that is not related to style tag or `_document.js` hack, please tell me, I will remove that answer as a bad answer

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!